# Moving object with mouse?

Tags: c#, math, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, draggable

I am currently trying to move a 2D texture in SharpDX. I can successfully move it but it jumps quite a bit every few frames. For example, if I'm dragging from bottom, right to top, left, I'll get an occasional jump where the origin of the image is at 75% bottom, right and then goes back to where it was a few frames later. This is quite odd in my opinion and I think it's possibly due to the event or the mouse position.

I'm updating the texture's position via the MouseMove event on my form:

```
private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        testSprite.Position = new Vector2(e.X - testSprite.Position.X,
                                          e.Y - testSprite.Position.Y);
    }
}
```

I think this is mostly due to the way I'm setting the `X` and `Y` values. Am I doing the math correctly here or is that what is causing my issue? I chose to write it this way because I don't want the texture's origin (0, 0: top, left) to jump to the mouse position, but instead move smoothly with the mouse from its current position.

---

### Clarity

- Is my math for assigning `X` and `Y` correct?

  - Yes: What else could cause this *jump*?
  - No: What is the correct math?

While debugging and trying different approaches I have learned that:

- Setting the `Position` to just `e.X,Y` gives smooth movement.

  - However, this jumps to mouse position which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragging process stages:

Start at MouseDown:
  - check whether object is touched
  -  remember `ObjectPos0`, `MousePos0`
  -  set `isDragging` flag (denotes that MouseDown is on object)

On MouseMove (if `isDragging`):
  - `ObjectPos = ObjectPos0 + (MousePos - MousePos0)`
  - redraw

On MouseUp (if `isDragging`):
   - fix final position
   - make needed work
   - clear `isDragging` flag